# Performance cost of DB::listen()

Tags: laravel, database, performance, listener

In our Laravel 8 app, we would like to leverage a `DB::listen()` call in our AppServiceProvider to catch any database query that takes longer than a specified length of time. Once caught, it can be logged, emailed, or sent to any third-party debugging service for investigation. This was found in a recent [LaravelDaily video](https://youtu.be/rJCnRqd_zDM) referencing [one of the guidelines](https://github.com/protonemedia/laravel-guidelines#database-and-eloquent) used at a Dutch software company.

Our concern is whether or not adding this listener would result in a performance hit on our database calls. If so, how much of a hit? We have an extensive database, with some tables reaching millions of records. We've indexed everything the best we can but are still worried that adding such a listener might slow down all of our queries too much.

Does anyone have any experience with `DB::listen()` and can speak to its performance cost?

Comment: You could always use Laravel's built-in benchmarking helper to test this in your environment. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#benchmarking

Comment: @Bennett Thanks, I wasn't aware of that tool! Unfortunately, it won't help in our app currently, as it's still on Laravel 8 while the Benchmark tool is only in Laravel 9 from what I can tell. (I've edited the original post to clarify it for future visitors.) We'll be moving to Laravel 9 in the coming weeks, though, so I'll definitely check it out then. Thanks again!